Option for hard covers in twin-loop wire-o binding?
My question concerns available options for hard covers in twin-loop wire-o binding, not concealing the wire at all; no spine, two separate covers.
I see notebooks for sale in big retailers that are twin-loop with very nice hard covers--thick, wrapped in embossed paper, with matching end leaves, and even with an elastic strap riveted to the back cover to keep the notebook closed. One such notebook, close in size to 8.5" by 11", was under $6.
I cannot find a local binder interested in making the covers. Akiles appears to have sold a limited selection (two options) but it has been discontinued. They were called Klassik.
I considered trying to make them myself using the materials from FastBind, which is 90pt chip board, a tacking sheet, and some sort of adhesive-backed end leaves. It requires a laminator to laminate the tacking sheet after printing on it and again after it has been glued to the boards.
I've yet to hear back from the supplier on what the specifications are for the laminator.
My questions are:

Is the FastBind approach of a good quality? It appears that you get one shot at getting the tacking on the board; no second chance to move it into the correct position. Is it feasible to just laminate a good piece of paper and glue it to the board rather than using a tacking sheet?
Are there other similar options?
I looked at 220lb cotton cardstock from Neenah papers (waiting for the sample) but not sure that it can be printed on or if it will fit through a printer with a backdoor feeder. Are there similar options of a sturdy enough cardstock that can be printed/laminated?

The books for this project range from 100 to 200 sheets of paper; and I need to make around 500-1000 maximum per month.
I don't mind working hard at it and substituting labor for a costly efficient machine that I cannot afford; but I'm just uncertain of the options and their quality.
Thank you for any guidance you may be able to provide.
